# HTML5 "time" input interval

Tags: html

Maybe i am just not searching properly, but does anyone know of a way to have the time input only increment using the spinner based on a preset interval. So if it is 10 minutes, have the up arrow go +10 mins, if the hour changes it would automatically go + an hour

8:50 - Up arrow hit ends with 9:00 -OR- 8:50 - Down arrow hit ends with 8:40

Answer (score 24):

Sure, just use the step attribute, where the step specifies the number of seconds to increment (60 sec x 10 mins = 600 seconds):

```
<input type="time" value="08:30:00" step="600">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MkxHE/)**

Comment: @DavidThomas - click in the minute field and then the arrow.

Comment: I stand corrected (I hadn't considered the hours/minutes might be independently controlled); original comment deleted and a +1. =)

Comment: I am looking more for something that just uses the arrows and not the clicking on each one. I dont show seconds in the box. I guess it just wont be possible using "time"

Comment: @AustinBest - not yet at least, plus support for that new input type is pretty thin.

Comment: You should use `value="08:30"`, as you don’t want to have seconds shown.

Comment: @AustinBest, the implementation of `<input type=time>` is browser-dependent. All the HTML5 CR requires is that the input widget accepts certain values only and yields a time in a specific format – it could do this using just a text box, or with speech input, or whatever, although a spinner is the intended *typical* implementation.

Comment: Not working on my system (Windows 10 + Chrome 89.0.4389.90)

Comment: Doesn't work in Microsoft Edge (Chromium version)