# Ruby on Rails: How do I assign a "step" attribute on a time_field to step in 30 minute intervals?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using form_with to generate a html form using Ruby on Rails. In this form_with, I'm using a fields_for to generate another section of forms that are attributes of the first form.

To make things simple, though, I simply want to know how I can restrict time selections to be in 30 minute increments.

For example, I am doing:

```
<%= form.fields_for employee_jobs do |assign_job| %> 
  <%= assign_job.time_field :time_start %> 
<%= end %>
```

How can I make it so I get a "step" attribute in the html time input node when I'm done? Right now, I'm trying to do:

```
<%= form.fields_for employee_jobs do |assign_job| %> 
  <%= assign_job.time_field(:time_start, :step=>600) %> 
<%= end %>
```

But it's not giving me the desired result.

Comment: I'm trying to make a time input that does something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285193/html5-time-input-interval

Comment: what's the generated HTML on the browser? it looks like that should work as you are using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I needed to do. Instead of using a time_field input, you can use the time_select input, and specify steps through the minute_step keyword.

Instead of:

```
<%= form.fields_for employee_jobs do |assign_job| %> 
  <%= assign_job.time_field :time_start %> 
<%= end %>
```

You can do:

```
<%= form.fields_for employee_jobs do |assign_job| %> 
  <%= assign_job.time_select :time_start {:minute_step => 30} %> 
<%= end %>
```

And this solved my problem.