# <input type="datetime-local"> How to display minutes with 15mns interval

Tags: javascript, html, forms, datetimepicker

I'm building some kind of booking app and I want to display to the user a datetimepicker input with only the possibility to book every quarter of an hour.

Example:

- 12:00
- 12:15
- 12:30
- 12:45

I couldn't find a way to do it with simple HTML. I need some guidance for this.

I tried to used "step" but apparently seem to only increment the value when clicking. This is not what I want.
My goal is to display only quarter values

Comment: You could use 2 drop downs next to each other. Drop down 1 is the hours, drop down 2 is the minutes (4 options from 00 to 45). In html that is the `select` tag.

Comment: So i drop the idea of "datetime-local" ? it seems incredible that it cannot be set

Comment: If you want a library you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/timepicker or search time picker on npmjs.

Comment: I need a date AND time picker + no jquery ..

Comment: "t seems incredible that it cannot be se" - Read up on browser history and versions and support for various input types and html features. Once you do that you will begin to appreciate the complexities that come with developing even seemingly simple html pages.

Comment: This is exaclty why i just said that. Such complexity and cannot even set an interval on a datetimepicker !

Comment: `I need a date AND time picker + no jquery` ← AFAIK there is no feature rich date time picker available that you will be able to use without the use of additional supporting libraries like jquery etc. You will either need multiple basic inputs to make this happen or opt to add supporting libraries to use a feature rich input.

Comment: Is there a way to acheive that in vanilla ?

Comment: Most of the browsers these days are open source. If you think you can add this functionality to a browser with no regression and sufficient testing, I'm sure they'd be happy to take a pull request. Otherwise, the `step` attribute is what you got.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I need some example please

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local. The main issue with this attribute is browser support, see also "Browser compatibility"

Comment: You said you had tried using the `step` attribute. Why would you need an example of something you've already tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 "time" input interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285193/html5-time-input-interval)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm here because i couldn't find the answer by myself. I tried it and did not have the expected result then I posted this to find guidance. You're just being rude

Comment: @secanNo Im'm sorry this isn't the expected result.I just want to display quarters of an hour

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) that is something you can configure with the `minuteIncrement` param

Comment: @secan Thanks for the suggestion, i just made a mistake wanted to reply to SebastianBrosch.

Comment: @AzoulayJason you tried with `step="900"` (instead of 600)? Can you also show what you have tried? You can't solve this by using native elements and functions. You should use a library or write your own code to solve this.

Answer (score -2):

```
let roundTime = (time, minutesToRound) => {

    let [hours, minutes] = time.split('.');
    hours = parseInt(hours);
    minutes = parseInt(minutes);

    // Convert hours and minutes to time in minutes
    time = (hours * 60) + minutes; 

    let rounded = Math.round(time / minutesToRound) * minutesToRound;
    let rHr = ''+Math.floor(rounded / 60)
    let rMin = ''+ rounded % 60

    //return rHr.padStart(2, '0')+'.'+rMin.padStart(2, '0')
    return rHr+'.'+rMin.padStart(2, '0')
}
```

usage: `roundTime(String(m),15);`

Comment: In what context is this being used? on the input/inside of a method?? last note. Does this alter the ui to only show 15 minute intervals on the calendar widget for datetime-local?